# Creating New Excel Sheet name using C#

Tags: c#, excel, split

I have here the codes where I'am confuse with

What I want is to create a program where in when I have 2 parent keys who both have 15 childs.. It will authomatically show its attributes on my excel sheet but then, the first keys can be created successfully.. apparently, the second keys is having an error since it is trying to save on the same worksheet as keys 1. Do anyone of you know how to use GetSheetNo? or CopySheet?

```
            int cntAddMember = 0;
            int cntPage = 0;
            string sheetName = dbReportDef.WorkSheet;
            string copyBaseSheet = "TEMP" + sheetName;
            string boforeSheet = sheetName;
            int boforeSheetPos = this.excel.GetSheetNo(boforeSheet);

 used to check the value of the sheetfirst before creating a new one,

 if (dbReportDef.IsAddMember)
            {
                if (this.detailNum < 0) { this.detailNum = GetDetailLine(sheetName, dbReportDef.CellNo); }              
                if (!this.excel.ExistSheet(copyBaseSheet))
 { this.excel.CopySheet(sheetName, copyBaseSheet, boforeSheetPos); }
            }
```

thanks :)

Comment: What are you using here? Excel Interop?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes,  I will post another code where in everytime you will attempt to create a sheetname, it will check its original value

Comment: Interop has fairly comprehensive documentation on the MSDN site. You should look there first to understand what the methods do, and then try out after modifying it as needed.

Comment: @shree.pat18 tried it but seems to be not working the way i want it to be. I was thinking maybe after the first code, i will create a condition where the keys will be in an array and the value of the sheet will be sheet = sheet + the index value of the array that would be 1 first, and after it post all the child, the index value will be 2, depends on how many keys are there